# Scoring Bases in Smash Up

Tags: smash-up

On my turn, I had tripped a base so it would score.  The other player played a special card that let him play any action as a special. He chose to play an action card that blocked the base from scoring until his next turn. I have a couple questions in this situation.

Does a base score as soon as it is tripped? Meaning, can he block it from scoring once it's tripped?

I think turn order says that a base scores after a minion and action card are played. Since I only played a minion, could I still play an action card on the tripped base, even after it is tripped? Or once it is tripped, are only special cards allowed?

If normally only special cards are allowed on a tripped base, could I play a regular action card in this situation, since my opponent stopped it from scoring?

Can I trip a base with an action card, wait for it to score and then play a minion on the new base or does scoring the base wait until the end of the turn?

Comment: What was the action he played that blocked the base from scoring?  If it was something that just changed the power present at the base, this would NOT stop scoring.

Answer (score 1):

The [order of play](http://www.alderac.com/smashup/files/2012/06/AEG-SU-Rulebook.pdf) is:

1. Play 1 Action and/or 1 Minion, in either order. (And those cards may do other things, including playing additional Actions/Minions.) You and/or your opponent can also play Special cards, if the Special card allows it. (If the Special can only be played "before the base scores", this is *not* when you can play that card.)
2. Score bases, if they've gone over the limit. (For each base, everyone can play "before the base scores" Special cards.) Once you start looking at a base to score it, it's going to finish being scored.
3. Draw 2 cards

So first off, bases will only be scored once you're doing playing *all* of the Actions/Minions that interest you in a turn. They do *not* score immediately. (Read the card your opponent played carefully: if it says something along the lines of "play an Action card as if it were a Special card that can be played before scoring", then your opponent played out of turn. If that's the case, he should have taken his card(s) back, allowed you to finish playing cards, and *then* re-played his card(s). On the other hand, if your opponent's card had much more loose terms, like "play an Action as a Special card", then they're allowed to play their card in the middle of the Action/Minion part of your turn. And then the base quite definitely wouldn't score, because you don't check for base scoring at all during the Action/Minion part of a turn.)

Secondly, once a base starts scoring, the *only* thing that can possibly stop the scoring/discarding process is a card that explicitly says something along the lines of "this base can't be scored." (Because rules on cards override rules in the rulebook.) If a Special or something reduces the total power at a base to below the threshold, that base *still scores*, because it had enough power when it *began* scoring. It's just going to look a little weird: perhaps someone manages to get 5 VP with 4 Power worth of minions, because that was the highest power at the time – or perhaps the base "scores" with no minions on it at all, and nobody gets any VP.

**TL:DR**

1. A base does not score as soon as it's tripped; it scores after Actions/Minions and before you draw 2 cards. Only check to see if a base has tripped once you're done with Actions/Minions.
2. Read your opponent's card *very carefully*. If it says "...before a base scores", then he played it too early. He needs to take it back and play it later once you're done playing Action/Minion cards.
3. You can't play an Action/Minion after a base scores, because all Actions/Minions should be done playing before you score any base.
4. All of the above *can* be overridden by card text, but the card must be explicit about what it's doing.